# how to limit php dom parsing results

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing

I am scrapping some results, when I scrape, I am getting 50 results. I want
to show only first 20 results, below is the code, how to limit results?

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

    $url = "http://espncricinfo.com/scores/match-100007";
    $html = file_get_html( $url );

    $posts = $html->find('div[type=tuple]');

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

    $matchtitle = $post->find('span[class=desigd]',0);

    $matchdate = $post->find('span[class=date]',0);

    echo $matchtitle;
    echo $matchdate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable to keep counting the results, and break from the for loop as soon as the count is `20`.

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

    $url = "http://espncricinfo.com/scores/match-100007";
    $html = file_get_html( $url );

    $posts = $html->find('div[type=tuple]');
$count = 0;
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
$count++
$matchtitle = $post->find('span[class=desigd]',0);

$matchdate = $post->find('span[class=date]',0);

echo $matchtitle;
echo $matchdate;
if($count == 20)
{
    exit();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you sir, it is working now. small correction $count++ should be as $count++;